# What does this error mean

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a map on my site, you can add location and info to this map. But on save and close I get this error

```
Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '$host' (25)' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=$hos...', '**************', '************')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

my code looks like this

```
    <?php
require("dbinfo.php");// database connections
// Get parameters from URL
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lng = $_GET["lng"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$time = $_GET["time"];
$description = $_GET["description"];
$sighting = $_GET["sighting"];
//Connect to database
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'error :' .$e->getMessage();
}
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare INSERT statement new sigting
        $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_maps (ID, map_client_name, client_time, client_lat, client_lng, client_description, client_sighting)  VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        // Assign parameters
        $stmt3->bindParam(1,$name);
        $stmt3->bindParam(2,$time);
        $stmt3->bindParam(3,$lat);
        $stmt3->bindParam(4,$lng);
        $stmt3->bindParam(5,$description);
        $stmt3->bindParam(6,$sighting);
        $stmt3->execute();
        $data[] = array("name"=>$name, "lat"=>round($lat,6), "lng"=>round($lng,6),"time"=>$time,"description"=>$description,"sighting"=>$sighting);
        //Data for success
        echo json_encode($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Message.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", phpsqlinfo_addrow.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

It takes 30 seconds or so and the i end up with an error msg. Please can someone help me sort this out

and then the dbinfo is

```
 $host="41.185.13.51;port=3307"; $database="kruger_park_live"; $username="sean_sql"; $password="******";
```

Comment: Check $host, $database, $username in your code

Comment: Your code is too messy to understand! Please post all of the code so we can help :)

Comment: @PhilCross there you go

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single or it will take `$host` as a value,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
```

If you have port in your host address than use it like,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
```

Read *[**Strings**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)* for more.

Comment: i have changed it to double quotes but then it takes 30 - 40 seconds and then I get Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '41.185.13.51' (110)' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=41.1...', 'sean_sql', 'Paaseiers01')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: If you are checking this at your local try giving `$host=locahost;`.

Comment: i am not testing on local server

Comment: What is your host address ? It seems you have port in it than check my updated answer.

Comment: okay i see let me try that my host address is mysql.spri.co.za

Comment: doing that leads to Data Loaded: error :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.spri.co.za' (110)<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

Answer (score 1):

You have set the errormode on and use exception for the error message. You didn't catch the exception so you will get this error.

To catch errors you will be using `try` and `catch` function.

for your code it will be this:

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'error :' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

By this you won't get the error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' ....`

The problem is in your db connection you should use double qoutes when you use variables in a string.

Change :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

To (**EDIT**)

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'error :' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

For more info about exception see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Check also all variables to be sure it is right. And does the server you use have access tot port 3307 on the other server? And are your sure about port 3307? because by default it is 3306

Comment: thank you, but doing what you recommended leads to this; Data Loaded: error :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '41.185.13.51' (110)<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br /      line 16:$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: 3307 is the correct port for the web africa server in south africva

Comment: see my change at to (EDIT). If you copy this. It should work notice that you have to make `$port = '3307';` on your dbinfo and change `$host="41.185.13.51;port=3307";` to `$host = '41.185.13.51';`

Answer (score 0):

Your database credentials are incorrect.

Please note that in the following line:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password);
```

You have used single quotes ' instead of double quotes "
When you want to use php variables within a string you should use double quotes.
You can fix this line on two ways.

A)

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
```

B)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database,$username,$password);
```

Comment: i have changed it to double quotes but then it takes 30 - 40 seconds and then I get Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '41.185.13.51' (110)' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=41.1...', 'sean_sql', 'Paaseiers01')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: hi okay it now doing this; Data Loaded: error :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.spri.co.za' (110)<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />. I made all the changes you requested to the code,

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single qoutes.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
```